# Why does my tvOS app eventually exit? And how can I stop it from doing that?

Tags: timeout, tvos, apple-tv

After noticing people in my company leaving our iPad app open all day on their desks to watch figures progress on a screen, and noticing we have some underutilized HDTVs on walls, I created a tvOS app and was able to put that information on the screen with minimal hassle, and we bought some fourth generation Apple TV units for the TVs. It's a huge hit.

However the one hitch is that the app doesn't stay alive indefinitely. I'm not sure why, but even though we've told tvOS to stay awake and not go to screen saver, every morning I come in and the app has exited and we're staring at the home screen. I have Crashlytics/Fabric installed on the app and I've had it crash a few times and send me emails about it but when I restart the app in the morning I don't get any emails, nor do I see any recurring crashes on their dashboard (it would likely be the same thing every day), so I don't think it's crashing.

So at this point it would make sense that perhaps there's some sort of time limit to how long an app can run that I'm running into.

I guess my first question is am I running into some sort of time limit at all, and the second question would be how could I prevent it from happening?

The intention is for this to only ever be an internal app and not go on the App Store so if there's some sort of way to do this that might get the app rejected by Apple that's not a problem since we're probably never going to release this to the public.

---

**UPDATE:**

So while Crashlytics/Fabric isn't telling me that the app crashed, the crash logs in the Devices window in Xcode is telling me that there are crashes.

Specifically it looks like at approximately 11:45PM every night, give or take a minute, it crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGILL) KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE` message. So I'm left wondering if there's something happening fifteen minutes to midnight in tvOS, or in what my app is doing, or if it's just a grand coincidence that the memory leak or whatever that might be causing this is happening at that time.

I guess one way to test it would be to make an app that does nothing and see if the same thing happens. The lack of answers on this post makes me think this is either an issue in my code (i.e., tvOS isn't enforcing some curfew or something) or that not many people are trying to use tvOS in this way.

Comment: Are you positive the application is not receiving a low memory warning and eventually being *killed*?

Comment: I have an app that I leave running on my tv for days at a time and it works fine, so it's almost certainly an issue in your code.